# SQL Database create table permission denied

Tags: sql, azure, permissions, permission-denied

I have few scripts which create some tables in some Azure Databases and these are fired up by init.sh. If I log in SSMS with the same user I am passing to the connection string and I run manually the scripts they successfully run with no problem. However, when I run my code I am getting this:

`CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'master'.`

I am using the same user as the one used to run manually. This makes no sense to me. What am I missing out? I tested the code on SQL DB running in a Docker Container in a VM and everything worked fine, tables were created. The code, should not be the issue.

Comment: easily solved: stop trying to create tables in the master DB

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind the error

```
CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'master'
```

is user doesn't have permission to create table in master database. So, follow below procedure to grant permissions in master database:

Connect the sql database to SSMS and open new query panel and select master database use the code below to grant the permission to the user:

```
USE Master;
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO <user>;
```

[image]

After granting the permission, I am able to create a table in the master database:

[image]

But, as per [this](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/tables-master-database/),

> The master database is a system database – it’s not really for you to poke around in and store stuff. We usually design different backup & recovery processes for the master database as opposed to user databases.

It's better to create tables in a dedicated database. For more information, you can refer to [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/173670/how-to-create-user-that-can-access-to-master-database).

Answer (score 0):

my mistake, the first error was the one from below and then the one from my original post:

```
USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect to a different database.
```

USE statement doesn't work for Azure SQL databases. And since this doesn't work I think it takes as default the master and tries to create there :)